# Help with weeds in lawn

Tags: weed-control

I live in Frisco, TX. I have clay soil in my area. I have a mix of weeds in my backyard (snaps below). Any idea what are the name of these weeds ?

Also, I used the Ortho weedkiller but it did not kill the weeds at all. Is there any recommendation on which weed killer to use ? I have a mix of St Augustine and Bermuda in my lawn. Thanks for your help and inputs !

https://www.lowes.com/pd/ORTHO-32-fl-oz-Weed-Killer/50252759
[image]

Comment: Look up Tenacity.

Answer (score 2):

Selective lawn weedkillers usually claim to kill *broad-leaved* weeds (as does the one in your link). The bad news is, most of your photos are not of broad-leaved weeds!

You basically have three options:

1. Hand weeding.
2. Spot application of a non-selective weedkiller like glyphosate to the individual weeds.
3. Nuke everything that's growing, then reseed or returf the lawn.

Since in your pictures the actual grass looks pretty miserable, option 3 will probably give the best results in the long term, but it's also the most expensive in terms of money (but not necessarily the most expensive in terms of person-hours to do the work).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have scheduled lawn aeration and will put down bermuda grass seeds after aeration since fall will be over soon. Should I just kill weeds this year and then do overseeding next year spring ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it may seem like a lot of work but so long as you have no physical disability stopping you then I would suggest you attempt to pull your weeds by hand. Don't expect to get it all cleared out in one go either. Could take several attempts to clear the whole yard.

In any case looks like you have some common weeds. I see crabgrass, clover, thistle or prickly lettuce and some type of Sorrel or bindweed or something like that... a creeper.

Comment: The bottom weed looks like prostrate spurge; best to pull it by hand before it goes to seed. It has a short tap root, so use a garden knife or wait until after a decent rain.